# AngularJS $scope variable loses value after $rootscope.$on function executes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS single-page application. We display a list of items in a table and users can drill-down to view the detail for a specific item. Some items have child items that can be drilled down as well. To visualize this consider a list of customers that can be drilled down to view customer detail. Each customer may have a list of orders and we can drill down to view order details.

This is the hierarchy of the data flow:

List of customers -> customer detail -> list of customer orders -> order detail

I have no trouble drilling down through this hierarchy but our users have requested "breadcrumbs" to be able to go back to an item's parent, for example, to be able to jump between a specific customer's order detail to the customer detail view.

This being a single-page application has made this a bit tricky but I have come up with a design which I thought would work but I'm having a bit of trouble with it. I'll spare you the gory details of how I am attempting to do that but the root of the problem is I need to pass data from the main view to the child view. I am using $rootscope.$broadcast to do this.

It all boils down to this. I can use the $rootscope.$on function to listen for the event raised by the $rootscope.$broadcast function and grab the data, in this case is that I want to view the detail for customer XYZ. However, I also need to perform some initialization in the child controller's "setup" function which is triggered by calling $(document).ready(setup); When I place a breakpoint in my code it seems that the $rootscope.$on function executes before the setup function executes. To attempt to get around this I tried setting storing that value as $scope.customerID $on function and reading that value in my setup function. For some reason $scope.customerID is undefined when I attempt to read the value. As a result, the "showDetail" function never executes.

MainController code:

```
function navigate(viewTemplate, itemID) {
    $scope.activeViewTemplate = viewTemplate; // Switches views specified by ng-include
    // (e.g. viewTemplate = 'customers.html', itemID = 12345)

    // If itemID is specified, show detail for that item
    if (itemID)
        $rootscope.$broadcast('viewDetail', { id: itemID });
}
```

CustomersController code:

```
// Calls the setup function when the view loads
$(document).ready(setup);

// Attach the event handler for the viewDetail event
$rootscope.$on('viewDetail', viewDetail);

// Handle the viewDetail event
function viewDetail(event, data) {
    if (data)
        $scope.customerID = data.id; // <-- Debugger shows this has a value
}

// Perform initialization and display customer detail of customerID is specified
function setup() {
  // initialization code goes here
  if ($scope.customerID) // <-- Always undefined!
    showDetail($scope.customerID);
}
```

Sorry if this is a bit complex. Basically I need to figure out why $scope.customerID doesn't retain it's value between the "viewDetail" and "setup". I've checked the rest of the code in my Customers controller and $scope.customerID isn't being set/cleared anywhere else. If I can't get this figured out I'll need to scrap my design and come up with something else.

Comment: Any chance you can isolate the problem and add it to a working code snippet or JSFiddle?

Comment: I would also highly suggest you not use $(document).ready() to invoke angular logic. This is not guaranteed to be run after the view loads.

Comment: @JoeHawkins How would you recommend invoking Angular logic? I'm using $(document).ready() in every controller in my application.

Comment: It depends on your setup. Can you post more code?

Comment: Not exactly, it's pretty complex. I did ditch the $(document).ready(setup) call with just setup() in all my controllers. Also the $scope.customerID variable doesn't really need to be attached to scope because it isn't used in the view. I changed it to a local variable (var customerID;) and I still get the same behavior. It seems that the variable value get wiped out between the "viewDetail" method where it's set and the "setup" method where it's read. Perhaps it has something to do with loading the view dynamically and then handling the "viewDetail" event (a timing issue?).

Comment: I discovered during my debugging session that there are two instances of my controller; the first is the one that handles the event and the second is the one that's associated with the view. Setting a value in one controller will not make that value available in another controller. I still haven't come up with a solution but I'm working on another project now so I will have to come back to this later.